# Java pattern \p{InBasicLatin} allows characters other than ASCII like from Korean and Tamil

Tags: java, regex

I was trying to accept characters only from ASCII [\p{InBasicLatin}] which suppose to allow characters within unicode range between 0000-007F but I found that it also allows character from languages like Tamil and Korean.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\P{InBasicLatin}]+$");
        while (true) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
            String word = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(word);
            System.out.println(pattern.pattern());
            System.out.println(word.length());
            System.out.println(pattern.matcher(word).matches());
        }
    }
}
```

---

Output:

안녕하세요
안녕하세요
^[\P{InBasicLatin}]+$
5
true

āśźŽȏ
āśźŽȏ
^[\P{InBasicLatin}]+$
5
true

வணக்கம்
வணக்கம்
^[\P{InBasicLatin}]+$
7
true

---

Where did I go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"^[\\P{InBasicLatin}]+$"` is all the characters NOT in BasicLatin because of capital `P`. You want `"^[\\p{InBasicLatin}]+$"` with lower-case `p`.

So, it's not "it also allows character from languages like Tamil and Korean", but "it only allows character from languages like Tamil and Korean" (and others)

Comment: Ok, I found that in the documents after you mentioned. Thanks